# How to cancel Android notifications?

Tags: android

I am making an app where the user can set an alarm based on GPS location. I only want 1 alarm to be active at any one time. So, when the user sets a 2nd alarm, I want to cancel the notification for the 1st alarm (then set a new notification for the 2nd alarm).

Right now, my notifications continue to stack up (as in I can't delete them, so they are all active). Here is my code where I am trying to delete the alarm and notification(s):

```
// Stop the location alarm activity
Intent intentAlarmService_delete = new Intent(v.getContext(), AlarmService.class);
stopService(intentAlarmService_delete); // I think this calls onDestroy() in AlarmService class ...

mNtf = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
mNtf.cancelAll();

Intent alarmIntent2 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), OneTimeAlarmReceiver.class);
PendingIntent pendingIntentAlarm = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), PENDING_INTENT_REQUEST_CODE1, 
    alarmIntent2, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
pendingIntentAlarm.cancel();
```

This is the onDestroy() function in my AlarmService.class (I'm not really sure when this is called...)

```
public void onDestroy(){
    super.onDestroy();
    mNtf.cancel(NOTIFICATION_ID1);

    Intent alarmIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), OneTimeAlarmReceiver.class);

    PendingIntent pendingIntentAlarm = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), PENDING_INTENT_REQUEST_CODE1, 
        alarmIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
    pendingIntentAlarm.cancel();

    Intent intentAlarmService = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AlarmService.class); 
    stopService(intentAlarmService); 

    mNtf.cancel(NOTIFICATION_ID1);
    mNtf.cancelAll();
}
```

Then, this is how I am setting a new alarm and notification:

```
Intent intentAlarmService2 = new Intent(v.getContext(), AlarmService.class);
startService(intentAlarmService2);
```

By the way, my AlarmService.class is working for sure.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, get rid of `getApplicationContext()`. You almost never need it and it is frequently the wrong choice. Replace it with `this`, since whatever you are calling `getApplicationContext()` on *is* a `Context`.

In the code you have listed, you never raise a `Notification`. Hence, it is difficult to help you figure out why you are getting more than one. Calling `cancelAll()` on the `NotificationManager` should get rid of all outstanding notifications from your application.

My best guess is that `onDestroy()` is not being called on your service. That would occur if something else is keeping the service in memory (e.g., you have an active bound connection to it via `bindService()`). Or, possibly, you have something strange in your `<service>` element in the manifest (e.g., an unnecessary `android:process` attribute) that is fouling up the `NotificationManager` `cancel()` operation.

Comment: Hmm, I checked all the things you suggested, but none of them work...
(I can't use "this" because I seem to get an error - this is probably cause all that code is in a "public void onClick(View v)" function.) + (i'm not using onBind(); ) + ( no strange stuff in <service> )

Comment: I am going to describe exactly what is happening:

I try to call cancelAll() on the NotificationManager, but:

1)   I set a new notification (it shows up in the "notification window" - when you swipe finger from top of screen to bottom)
2)   I delete the notification (it disappears from "notification window"
3)   I set a new notification ***(it shows up in the "notification window", BUT then the previous notification (which was deleted) shows up on top of the newest notification (which was just set), and the 2 notifications keep flickering / alternating in the "notification window"

Comment: @Yasir Malang: "I can't use "this" because I seem to get an error" -- you are in an inner class, then, and need to use `MyOuterClass.this` (substituting your activity class name for `MyOuterClass`).

Comment: `cancelAll()` was what I was looking for.

Comment: in my fault: I call cancelAll and can() after call unregisterReceiver(), just call before function unregisterReceiver() in service :))

Answer (score 2):

You need to make sure you are always referencing the same instance of your NotificationManager. Different instances will produce different notifications. I'd recommend using a service to manage notifications.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals.html

Comment: `NotificationManager` is merely a proxy to a system service running in another process. I have a sample project (http://github.com/commonsguy/cw-android/tree/master/Notifications/Notify1/) that does not work the way you describe. If you have evidence that `NotificationManager` works as you describe, please point me to it!

Comment: Using different NotificationManager instance will not generate different notifications. It all depends on you Notification Id.