# Single line notification that is shown across the status bar?

Tags: android, notifications

just a simple question: How to make the single-line notification that will disappear after a short time.

Just like Whatsapp's:

[image: Whatsapp notification]

My current notification code is still very basic:

```
Intent intent = new Intent("com.example.MyChat");
PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, 0);
Notification notification = new Notification.Builder(context)
        .setContentTitle("New message from " + name)
        .setContentText(message)
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher).setContentIntent(pIntent)
        .getNotification();

notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;

NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context
        .getSystemService(context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
notificationManager.notify(0, notification);
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is called the "ticker" and it is shown briefly by the status bar if you set the `tickerText` property of your Notification.

See [setTickerText](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.Builder.html#setTicker%28java.lang.CharSequence%29).

Comment: Thanks, it's hard to search this in Google because I don't know the correct term

Answer (score 1):

You can use [AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html) to invoke after a short time, say 5 seconds.

Also you can use a service, which gets launched, when first time the notification appears and it could cancel the notification after some time.

here you can cancel Notification using,

```
NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationManager.cancel(NOTFICATION_ID);
```

Have a look at this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3461743/1626878), it might help you as well.

Comment: Is there any built-in `Notifiation` method for this?

Comment: No, there is no built in method to cancel notification after some time. either you have to click it or you could invoke a service when application is launched, which sjould cancel it after some time.

Comment: I'm not cancelling the notification, I just want to show the text across the status bar. Is there a way?

Comment: text or a notification.? be specific. for text, we have a very beautifull feature, ***TOAST***.

Comment: Sorry, I mean the notification. Just like in *Whatsapp* when new message come, it will display a statement across status bar (like picture above). But with my code, it only shows the notification icon which easily ignored.

Comment: Yes I have read those methods but it doesn't seem to solve my problem. I don't want to cancel the notification, I want it to show a **snippet** of the title when the notification arrived. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Sorry to say, I cant understand, what exactly you want to do. Do you want to show a message snippet in the notification area or somewhere else. and as far as the above picture is concerned, I'm not able to see it.

Comment: Here I reupload the image http://imgur.com/3krGb when we receive whatsapp or email, you can see a text snippet in the status bar above (usually for time, battery, signal)

Comment: as for image, imgur.com is blocked in our office, so sorry. as far I can say, email also works on push notification and I think whatsapp to works on it. for that you need a huge setup(GCM). I prefer not to mess with it.

Comment: what you were talking was something matching to GCM notification. otherwise, a service could have solved your issue, it will seem similar like a notification that disappears after some time.